# How to recognize when WiFi is not connected due to wrong password?

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager, wifi

I've already made app that scans WiFi aps in a list and connects to a selected ap. But I still don't get what is returned if I put wrong password.

Does `WifiManager` (or `WifiConfiguration`) returns something if I put wrong password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are the valid state the wifi can be :[taken from android doc]

[image]

If you have wifiInfo object you would get its state via :

```
SupplicantState supplicantState= wifiInfo.getSupplicantState();
```

Comment: the only log I could see was INACTIVE when failed to connect. however, it sometimes returns INACTIVE as well when connecting with right password..I'm really confused right now